# python Iterative loop through columns of dataframe

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Working on a problem, I have the following dataframe in python

```
    week    hour    week_hr     store_code  baskets
0   201616  106     201616106   505         0
1   201616  107     201616107   505         0
2   201616  108     201616108   505         0
3   201616  109     201616109   505         18
4   201616  110     201616110   505         0
5   201616  106     201616108   910         0
6   201616  107     201616106   910         0
7   201616  108     201616107   910         2
8   201616  109     201616108   910         3
9   201616  110     201616109   910         10
```

Here "hour" variable is a concat of "weekday" and "hour of shop", example weekday is monday=1  and hour of shop is 6am then hour variable = 106, similarly cal_hr is a concat of week and hour. I want to get those rows where i see a trend of no baskets , i.e 0 baskets for **rolling 3 weeks**. in the above case i will only get the **first 3 rows**. i.e. for store 505  there is a continuous cycle of 1 baskets from **106 to 108**. But i **do not** want the **rows (4,5,6)** because even though there are 0 baskets for 3 continuous hours but the hours are actually NOT continuous. **110 -> 106 -> 107** . For the hours to be continuous they should lie in the **range** of **106 - 110.**. Essentially i want all stores and the respective rows if it has 0 baskets for continuous 3 hours on any given day.     Dummy output

```
    week    hour    week_hr     store_code  baskets
0   201616  106     201616106   505         0
1   201616  107     201616107   505         0
2   201616  108     201616108   505         0
```

Can i do this in python using pandas and loops? The dataset requires sorting by store and hour. Completely new to python (

Comment: Additional info, can i loop in the following way, loop through each hour, but for each hour check for the next 3 hours, if the baskets in those hours are 0 , then return those rows,

Comment: I would suggest first getting a list with all element that have baskets = 0. (create a dictionnary with store_code as keys, and list of hours where baskets = 0 as value. Then, find any three or more elements in a row for the list corresponding to each store_code, and finally using the list of 'good hours & store_code' to get the full data from the db. I'll try to do a more detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Sort by store_code, week_hr
2. Filter by 0
3. Store the subtraction between df['week_hr'][1:].values-df['week_hr'][:-1].values so you will get to know if they are continuos.
4. Now you can give groups to continuous and filter as you want.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd

   # 1
   t1 = df.sort_values(['store_code', 'week_hr'])

   # 2
   t2 = t1[t1['baskets'] == 0]

   # 3
   continuous = t2['week_hr'][1:].values-t2['week_hr'][:-1].values == 1
   groups = np.cumsum(np.hstack([False, continuous==False]))
   t2['groups'] = groups

   # 4
   t3 = t2.groupby(['store_code', 'groups'], as_index=False)['week_hr'].count()
   t4 = t3[t3.week_hr > 2]
   print pd.merge(t2, t4[['store_code', 'groups']])
   ```

There's no need for looping!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will the above code look for pattern of 3 or more consecutive occurences of 0. Can i create an index for each week day and hour. Example . For week 201616 and hour of monday 106 and so on.i can create a variable that has index. So the sequence become actual number. Say for 201616106 value is 1 then 201616107 value is 2..and so on..or may be i dont even need to do it? Can you please explain in detail. Still learning python. Newbie here

Comment: The code I provided will work for that dataframe you specified and will detect 3 or more consecutive 0's for the same store_code, week_hr. The relevant code is `t4 = t3[t3.week_hr > 2]` where week_hr is the count of consecutive occurrences (so it is filtering more than 2 consecutive occurrences). There's no need to create index, the week_hr will work just fine with groupby clause. Have you run it? Did it work?

Comment: this has worked great , just that  i am unable to understand the part after #3. What does hstack do ? Can you please explain. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: When you subtract next-current your actual array will have a -1 length. Ex: 4,5,6,7 will lead to True,True,True, so I have to `hstack` to add  the first element as False to be able to add a column with the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve:

1. Sort by store_code, week_hr
2. Filter by 0
3. Group by store_code
4. Find continuous

Code:

```
t1 = df.sort_values(['store_code', 'week_hr'])

t2 = t1[t1['baskets'] == 0]

grouped = t2.groupby('store_code')['week_hr'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())    

for store_code, week_hrs in grouped.iteritems():
    print(store_code, week_hrs)
    # do something
```

Comment: Thanks a lot cuong. Will the above code look for pattern of 3 or more consecutive occurences of 0. What does apply do ? What is tolist().what is iteritems? Can you please explain in detail. Still learning python. Newbie here.